# When I call an async method frequently, how to make each call executed in the called order in C#

Tags: xamarin, asynchronous

I am working on a Xamarin.forms project which has a ScrollView with a child of a StackLayout, whose child is a Label.

```
<ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
            x:Name="MessageScroll" BackgroundColor="Gainsboro">
      <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Beige" Margin="2"
                   x:Name="MessageStack" Spacing="0">
             <Label Text="Messages"/>
      </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I want this to be a message window.
I will add onto this StackLayout new labels with messages.

I made a label with a new message(e.Message), added it onto Stacklayout, and then, scroll down the ScrollView show the last added label at the bottom of the ScollView.

```
            Label newLabel = new Label();
            newLabel.Text = e.Message;
            MessageStack.Children.Add(newLabel);
            await MessageScroll.ScrollToAsync(newLabel, ScrollToPosition.End, false);
```

the problem is ScrollToAsync doesn't ensure the last added label to be at the bottom when I added multiple message labels consecutively in a short period of time.
It seems because each call of ScrollToAsync is executed asynchronously so the last call for it wouldn't complete last.

How can I make this to work as what I want?

Comment: Hi , if answer be helpful and solved problem , remember to mark it when you have time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you await the ScrollToAsync it will wait for scroll action to be completed. Anyway, here is a solution to scroll to bottom, you can give it a try.

```
async Task AddLabel(MessageEventArgs e)
{
    Label newLabel = new Label();
    newLabel.Text = e.Message;
    MessageStack.Children.Add(newLabel);
    await MessageScroll.ScrollToAsync(0, MessageStack.Height, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, dbvega. it works. Actually, I saw that overload but didn't understand what those positions stand for. can you add more comments on them?

Comment: @BigSquare The two first argument are X and Y (respectivily) positions of the finished scroll. The third argument is a flag for animation (true/false if you want animation). For more information, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.scrollview.scrolltoasync). If the answer works for you please accept it.